# Graph comments in a graph like a label?

Tags: excel, graph

I have come across this several times and I was wondering if it is possible at all.
Let's say I have 3 columns, one with numerical values, one with time values and a third column with text (1-3 words). I then create a graph with the numerical values (y axis) and the time (x axis). When I then hover over the individual data points on the graph it shows me their numerical values. Is there a way to also show the text associated with that value?

To put it in context, I am plotting noise values for a day and would love to hover over the graph, in particular the peaks and then have a text appear that tells me what the noise was related too, what noise source (e.g. airplane, truck etc).

Is this possible? I was thinking of maybe plotting a second axis for the comments and maybe just plot them all at the same y value but then I am still left with the question on how to display the text comment?

Any ideas?

Cheers
Sandra

Comment: I think what you are looking for is chart tooltips

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/520326-display-cell-contents-via-tooltip.html

Answer (score 1):

Tushar Mehta has an add-in for that [here](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/software/chart_hover_label/)

- It has been tested for Excel 97 to 2002, which are all pretty old versions.
- The charting engine has changed completely from[excel-2007](/questions/tagged/excel-2007), and the menus have gone, so chances are that this tool may no longer work.

I have not seen anything like this done in more recent Excel versions. Probably because it is not an easy task to achieve.